# How does facebook saves and generates notifications and displays us?

Tags: php, jquery, comet

Ever Since I had started my web-programming, I was always on a question... how is facebook very very dynamic... then slowly understood the capabilities of powerful tools like Javascripts, PHP, jquery and so on... But I never got out of a question related about the notification generation.... i.e. when we do something on others wall or profile like postings; the notification of something being done is straight-forward to reach the user's page ... but what actually makes the notifications read?? Is it a database injection for retrieving the information or something more likely to XML-reading?? Can anybody answer me just the actual factor for that?

The real-time notification is done through the comet .. I read the article and understood but what about getting the notifications read?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, if i get your question. But if you are wonderuing, how you are informed about an action someone else takes, that involves you (e.g. writes something on your wall), i can give you my personal guess.

Whenever someone does something, that affects someone else, facebook has some mechanisms to generate the notifications (quite basic).

Every page you have open from facebook regularly sends a "whats new?"-Ajax request to facebook.

If there is something new, this request gets this information, which is then processed on client-side.

BAM - MAGIC can be easy.

If this was not your question, feel free to explain ^^

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not share its code, so one can only make educated guesses as to how its sharing its notifications. However if you wanted to say, duplicate what they are doing I would use an event driven model.

You already said that you know they use Comet. What that gives them is a constant connection from a client to to the server, this connection can just be registered as a listener on the server. When another client updates something on the page, an event will be fired, the listener will pick it up and update the page. No DB interaction needed.